# Complex Analysis, bounding modulus of derivative of a function with given constrains

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've encountered the following problem:

> Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the unit disk. Let $f$ be an entire function,
> such that $f(0)=3+4i$ and $\forall z \in \mathbb{D}:|f(z)|\leq 5$.
> Find $f'(0)$

I suppose we can apply the maximum modulus principle in some way but I don't see how I can make any statement about the derivative. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You're right, and now the hint: $\;|f(0)|=5\;$, so $\;|f|\;$ attains its maximum value on $\;\Bbb D\;$ at the point $\;z=0\;$ , so...can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ was not constant, then $|f|$ would have no maximum. But $|f(0)|=5\geqslant|f(z)|$, for each $z\in\Bbb D$, and therefore the maximum of $|f|$ is attained at $0$. So, $f$ is constant. It follows from this that $f'(0)=0$.